# multiprocessing hangs due to a long dictionary of strings

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have a piece of code that replaces specific multi-word chemicals with versions where hyphens are placed instead of spaces in between. (e.g. 'magnesium oxide' replaced with 'magnesium-oxide')

For a shorter list of chemicals, the code below takes almost a day to run (yes, even with multiprocessing). For the current list, it started to hang after a day. I was wondering whether there was a bottleneck leading to "hanging". FYI, length of chemical list is 418k.

```
import re
import time
import numpy
import pandas
import pickle
from datetime import datetime
from multiprocessing import Pool 

#Introduce a class to preprocess the data more efficiently
class Hyphenizer:
    
   def __init__(self, chem_pattern, chem_name_hyp_dict): 
       
       #chem_pattern is a regex pattern with union of chemical names surrounded by word boundaries 
       #(e.g. r'\bmagnesium oxide\b')

       self.chem_pattern = chem_pattern
       
       #chem_name_hyp_dict is a dictionary where keys correspond to multi-word chemical names 
       #and values to multi-word names with hyphens e.g. {'magnesium oxide': 'magnesium-oxide'}

       self.chem_name_hyp_dict = chem_name_hyp_dict
       
   def hyphenize_chemicals(self, series): 

       hyphenized_text = []

       #Series are a series of texts       
       series_as_list = series.tolist()
       
       for text in series_as_list:
           
           #If a multi word chemical is present in the text
           if bool(re.search(self.chem_pattern, text)):
    
           #Replace multi word chemical instances with their hyphenized versions which
           #are both specified in a dictionary
               text = self.chem_pattern.sub(
                   lambda match: self.chem_name_hyp_dict[match.group(0)], text)
               
           hyphenized_text.append(text)    
        
       return hyphenized_text

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    
    # Read the cleaned article data - ignore some columns as they are unnecessary
    articles = pandas.read_csv("../data/abstracts_clean.csv", 
                               error_bad_lines = False, warn_bad_lines = True, 
                               usecols = ['doi', 'abstract', 'doc_id', 
                                          'clean_abstract'])

    #Introduce chunks of certain size to the parallelization process (100 texts per chunk)
    chunks = numpy.array_split(articles['clean_abstract'], 71)
    
    #Bring the pickle object containing multi-word chemicals list with word boundaries around them
    with open('../data/chem_w_bound_w_filt.pkl', 'rb') as f: 
        chem_name_list_w_boundaries = pickle.load(f)

    #Compile a regex pattern of the list above
    chem_pattern = re.compile("|".join(chem_name_list_w_boundaries))

    #Bring a dictionary of multi word chemicals mapped to their hyphenized versions
    with open('../data/chem_name_hyp_dict_filt.pkl', 'rb') as f: 
        chem_name_hyp_dict = pickle.load(f)

    #Collect all hyphenized chunks here
    hyphenized_abs_lil = []
    
    #create a Hyphenizer instance
    hyphenizer = Hyphenizer(chem_pattern, chem_name_hyp_dict)
    
    #Go over chunks to introduce them to Pool
    for i, clean_abs_chunk in enumerate(chunks):
        
        #Split the chunk further into smaller chunks (25 texts per process)
        smaller_chunks = numpy.array_split(clean_abs_chunk, 4)
              
        #Track how long it takes per a chunk   
        now = datetime.now()
        now_formatted = now.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        print('It is {} right now'.format(now_formatted))
            
        with Pool(4) as pool:     
             
            hyphenized_abs = pool.map(
                hyphenizer.hyphenize_chemicals, smaller_chunks)
            
        hyphenized_abs_lil.append(hyphenized_abs)
```

**EDIT**

abstracts_clean.csv contains abstracts and some information about them. The column I am operating on 'clean_abstracts' looks like this:

```
articles.clean_abstract.head()
0    sausages are one of the oldest processed foods...
1    populations of pollinating insects are in conc...
2    it was highlighted that the original article c...
3    foodborne pathogens are a major cause of diarr...
4    a sizable proportion of the world population i...
```

chem_name_hyp_dict maps multi-word chemicals to their hyphenized versions.

```
list(chem_name_hyp_dict.items())[: 5]
[("9beta-d-ribofuranosylpurine cyclic 3',5'-phosphate",
  "9beta-d-ribofuranosylpurine-cyclic-3',5'-phosphate"),
 ('2-methoxy-17betaestradiol 3-o-(beta-d-glucuronide)',
  '2-methoxy-17betaestradiol-3-o-(beta-d-glucuronide)'),
 ('n(3)-(4-methoxyfumaroyl)-2,3-diaminopropionic acid',
  'n(3)-(4-methoxyfumaroyl)-2,3-diaminopropionic-acid'),
 ('calcium disodium ethylenediamine tetraacetic acids',
  'calcium-disodium-ethylenediamine-tetraacetic-acids'),
 ('trans-1,2-ethylenedicarboxylic acid dimethyl ester',
  'trans-1,2-ethylenedicarboxylic-acid-dimethyl-ester')]
```

Comment: You have a single regex with 418k branches that you're applying to N nebulous texts? No wonder it's slow.

Comment: A ternary search trie may be an alternative to the regex.

Comment: Can you provide a small sample of the `abstracts_clean.csv` and `chem_name_hyp_dict_filt.pkl`?

Comment: provided first entries of both under edit at the end of OP @JonSG :)

Answer (score 0):

I would start by reshaping your lookup slightly to be a nested dictionary tree. I think that would allow you to search the tree by word/token in a manner that might be faster than what you are doing now.

**Update**: I have altered the lookup structure to support partial key overlaps via a leaf and branch

**Note:** I edited your test data slightly to include some potential cases such as partial matches. Let me know if that helps at all.

```py
abstracts = [
    "sausages are one of foo bar the oldest processed 9beta-d-ribofuranosylpurine cyclic 3',5'-phosphate foods",
    "populations of foo bar baz pollinating 9beta-d-ribofuranosylpurine cyclic 4',5'-phosphate insects are in conc",
    "2-methoxy-17betaestradiol 3-o-(beta-d-glucuronide) it was highlighted that the original article c",
    "foodborne pathogens are a 9beta-d-ribofuranosylpurine cyclic major cause of diarr",
    "a sizable proportion of the world population i calcium disodium ethylenediamine tetraacetic acids"
]

translations = dict([
    ("foo bar", "foo-bar"),
    ("foo bar baz", "foo-bar-baz"),
    ("9beta-d-ribofuranosylpurine cyclic 3',5'-phosphate", "9beta-d-ribofuranosylpurine-cyclic-3',5'-phosphate"),
    ("9beta-d-ribofuranosylpurine cyclic 4',5'-phosphate", "9beta-d-ribofuranosylpurine-cyclic-4',5'-phosphate"),
    ('2-methoxy-17betaestradiol 3-o-(beta-d-glucuronide)', '2-methoxy-17betaestradiol-3-o-(beta-d-glucuronide)'),
    ('n(3)-(4-methoxyfumaroyl)-2,3-diaminopropionic acid', 'n(3)-(4-methoxyfumaroyl)-2,3-diaminopropionic-acid'),
    ('calcium disodium ethylenediamine tetraacetic acids', 'calcium-disodium-ethylenediamine-tetraacetic-acids'),
    ('trans-1,2-ethylenedicarboxylic acid dimethyl ester', 'trans-1,2-ethylenedicarboxylic-acid-dimethyl-ester')
])

## -------------------------
## reshape the lookup a bit so we can
## search by partial matches.
## -------------------------
translations2 = {"leaf": None, "branches": {}}
for translation, value in list(translations.items()):
    target = translations2
    parts = translation.split()
    for token in parts:
        target = target["branches"].setdefault(token, {
            "leaf": None,
            "branches": {}
        })
    target["leaf"] = value
## -------------------------

## -------------------------
## read each abstract
## -------------------------
for abstract in abstracts:
    tokens = iter(abstract.split(" "))
    abstract = []

    for token in tokens:

        ## -------------------------
        ## this is not the start of a potential match
        ## -------------------------
        if token not in translations2["branches"]:
            abstract.append(token)
            continue
        ## -------------------------

        ## -------------------------
        ## This is a potential match so see how far we can take it
        ## -------------------------
        lookup = translations2
        skipped_tokens = []
        while token in lookup["branches"]:
            lookup = lookup["branches"][token]
            skipped_tokens.append(token)

            try:
                token = next(tokens)
            except StopIteration:
                break
        ## -------------------------

        ## -------------------------
        ## Figure out how to increment the accumulator
        ## -------------------------
        if lookup["leaf"]:
            abstract.append(lookup["leaf"])
        else:
            abstract.extend(skipped_tokens)
        ## -------------------------

    print(" ".join(abstract))
## -------------------------
```

When run you should see:

```
sausages are one of foo-bar oldest processed 9beta-d-ribofuranosylpurine-cyclic-3',5'-phosphate
populations of foo-bar-baz 9beta-d-ribofuranosylpurine-cyclic-4',5'-phosphate are in conc
2-methoxy-17betaestradiol-3-o-(beta-d-glucuronide) was highlighted that the original article c
foodborne pathogens are a 9beta-d-ribofuranosylpurine cyclic cause of diarr
a sizable proportion of the world population i calcium-disodium-ethylenediamine-tetraacetic-acids
```

Comment: thanks, I appreciate it :) yes partial matches would be an issue. also looking at  translations2 dictionary, I think it only keeps one element of keys and values where the key is the last word of the multi-word chemical (e.g. {'oxide': 'magnesium-oxide'}), it being only one element can be fixed.

Comment: The leaf holds the final result, but it is the tree that is important. If you run the code you will see that it works correctly for the test data.  I will update the answer later today with a tree that will support partial overlaps.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a lookup structure that supports keys with overlaps. Let me know if that improves the speed for you.

Comment: thank you so much, I will look into it, in a couple of days :) @JonSG